# MySQL Syntax Error When Using Data From MSSQL Imported Tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have imported a number of tables (structure and data) from an MSSQL DB into mysql - all data is in UTF8

I can pull data from the old tables, but when I use any of the data from the imported tables in a query from PHP I get a syntax error like this:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''data' at line 1

for this query

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE field='data'
```

This only happens if executing the query from PHP, if I echo out the query from php and then copy, paste and execute the query from phpmyadmin then it runs fine.

Any ideas???

I'm using PHP 5.2.17 running on Apache 1.3.42 and MySQL 4.1.22-standard

Comment: Are you *really* using the normal apostrophe `'`? Also your PHP code for executing the query would help.

Comment: I say it again, please post your PHP code, too. and don't simplify too much if you can't guarantee that the simplified version will also trigger the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you using query like this then query should be :

E.G 
"SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE field='data'";
or
'SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE field="data"';

Please check for "Field" data-type whether is Varchar or sumthing else!

Comment: First, the field type has nothing to do with an syntax error. Second, How's that different to the query he posted?

Comment: To clarify, it is not the formatting of the query. It is only if I use data that has been imported from MSSQL in a query run from PHP that the error occurs - if I echo out the query from my PHP script and execute it from phpmyadmin - then it runs fine. My guess is that it has something to do with the data.

Comment: Have solved this by exporting the data from the imported tables to XML and then used a PHP XML Parser to import into DB. Long way round but it solved the problem.